# How to convert value of array to integer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have next JS code:

```
chart1.data = [['Component', 'cost']];

chart1.type = "PieChart";
    angular.forEach(values, function(key, item) {
        chart1.data.push([item, key]);
});
```

How I can to `key` like as integer value in `push()`?

Because now I get this value in console as: `0: "questions"1: "3"`, where "3" is string.

Comment: I don't understand which part you're asking about, but... `parseInt()`

Comment: Try `key.parseInt()` for explicit casting; you could use `key*1` for implicit type conversion.

Comment: You realize you have created a two-dimensional array with those duplicated square brackets, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parseInt to convert strings into Int
parseInt("4") will return 4

Comment: Specify the radix (`parseInt("4", 10)`) to ensure it doesn't accidentally parse the string as hex or binary